# MySQL create Table error on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

Creating a database for a class in PHP and MYSQL. Running into an error when creating the database, phpMyAdmin gives me a useless error message. (Software that gives a better error message would be awesome BTW)

phpMyAdmin error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE customers ( customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto increment, fir' at line 1

```
USE isys288_gottfrk 
CREATE TABLE customers ( customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
auto increment, first_name carchar(20) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id), INDEX full_name (last_name, first_name) ) engine =
innodb;
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after `USE isys288_gottfrk`. Replace `carchar(20)` after `first_name` with `varchar(20)`

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in your code.

```
USE isys288_gottfrk;
CREATE TABLE customers 
( 
  customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id), 
  INDEX full_name (last_name, first_name) 
) engine = innodb;
```

I suggest you use a DB tool like *MySQL Workbench* to generate your tables. Then you can see the problems right away.

Comment: Thank you, and though I can't connect directly to my database using Workbench yet :(, it's Script editor is waaaaaaaay better than phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Juergen d edited your question for formatting, this might have helped you as well: Your initial statement was all on one line, so the error was flagged in that one line. If you edited it on multi lines (like in your question, or better in his answer) you might have gotten a better message, e.g. one that flags that the line containing `carchar(20)` contains a problem (it's even better the way he has it in his answer, but it correctly uses `varchar(20)`, not flagging a problem)

Yes, it would be nice if error messages would immediately flag the problem, but sometimes it's already better when the input is formatted in a more human-readable way. I've tested the same with a multiline statement, mysql stated

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
 the right syntax to use near 'carchar(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, first_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
, last_name VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
, INDEX full_name (last_name, first_name)
) ENGINE = INNODB ;
```

You can use some GUI clients like [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) for this.